# Trouble at comparing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have **'shared.checkedFacility'** scope array in controller which read something like:

```
[14, 49, 93, 122, 44, 40, 88, 83, 65, 9, 38, 28, 8, 53, 125, 155]
```

and i am dynamically generating two dimensional array in front end where, for example, single dimentional array from '**shared.facilities[$parent.$index]**' read like

```
{"0":56,"1":13,"2":49,"3":3,"4":11,"5":7,"6":19,"7":4,"8":9,"9":131,"10":21}
```

Now i am comparing this two array in ng-show argument like

```
containsAny(shared.checkedFacility,shared.facilities[$index])
```

Where as function defination is like

```
function containsAny(source, target) {
        console.log("contains called");
        var result = source.filter(function(item) {
            return target.indexOf(item) > -1
        });
        return (result.length > 0);
    }
```

But some how this function is not returning true or false, how to make it work?

Please rescue me since i am afresh here in Angular or in Javascript Env straight from PHP.

Comment: `shared.facilities[$parent.$index]` appears to be an `Object` , not an `Array` ?

Comment: @guest271314 and then how to convert it to array in frontend so that my containsAny function which basically compare array elements work?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.map()`; see post

Comment: Fix the object structure and you would have a more efficient lookup. Where does object come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `.map()` to create an array from `shared.facilities[$parent.$index]`

```js
// `shared.checkedFacility`
var checkedFacility = [14
                       , 49
                       , 93
                       , 122
                       , 44
                       , 40
                       , 88
                       , 83
                       , 65
                       , 9
                       , 38
                       , 28
                       , 8
                       , 53
                       , 125
                       , 155
                      ];
// shared.facilities[$parent.$index]
var facilities = {
  "0": 56,
  "1": 13,
  "2": 49,
  "3": 3,
  "4": 11,
  "5": 7,
  "6": 19,
  "7": 4,
  "8": 9,
  "9": 131,
  "10": 21
};
// create an array having values contained in `facilities`
var arr = Object.keys(facilities).map(function(prop, index) {
  return facilities[prop]
});

console.log(arr)

function containsAny(source, target) {
  console.log("contains called");
  var result = source.filter(function(item) {
    return target.indexOf(item) > -1
  });
  return (result.length > 0);
}
// pass `arr` as second parameter to `containsAny`
var res = containsAny(checkedFacility, arr);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you guest271314, you have saved my lots of time. You had great catch as well solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is failing on:

```
target.indexOf(item)
```

because target in your example is an **Object** and not an **Array**, so you can't call **indexOf** function.

So you are most likely getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: target.indexOf is not a function

To solve that, you have to pass an Array as *target* instead of passing an Object.